# What should I do about a cat polymorphed into an invisible monster in Nethack?

Tags: nethack

I am a lawful human Valkyrie that crawled down the dungeon to the Oracle with a cat and a dog.  The problem is that my cat accidentally stepped on a polymorph trap and he turned into an invisible monster.  I do not have related intrinsics or extrinsics and I cannot see him, nor do I know what kind of monster he is now.

What is the best way to cope with such a pet?

Comment: What actual problem is this causing? It's important to say the problem you want us to solve if you want us to solve it.

Comment: It's hard to walk an invisible pet around the dungeon along with you, and if you decide to leave him at the Oracle, he may become hostile when you came back there later.

Comment: Have you considered just polymorphing it again when you get the opportunity? Also it should be easy enough to walk around with it if you get a leash somewhere, unless I am forgetting something.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since the polymorph trap doesn't disappear until you step on it, just push your pet onto the trap again (after letting it heal up so it doesn't die of systemic shock). it should turn into some other, ideally non-invisible monster.

If the polymorph trap is gone there are usually some in the lowest levels of the Gnomish Mines.

Comment: Thank you for your advice, Lawton. How can I step my pet onto the trap when he's invisible?

Comment: Well getting him between you and the trap can be tough although you can do things like drop cursed items on the ground which he wont want to step on. Also a leash will help.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I'd probably abandon this pet and tame a new one. Sounds much easier to me than your current predicament. (then again, I'm hopeless at this game)

Answer (score 0):

If you have a magic whistle, you can stand next to the MT and repeatedly apply it until the pet lands on the trap (if it's invisible, you are more likely to attack it than displace even empty-handed). Another option is to lock your pet in with the MT for a while and hope for the best (as long as you keep it fed and check up on it every 3-500 turns, you can explore nearby levels and possibly find something that will apply. Sokoban is one level down from Oracle, and pets just get in the way there anyway).   A stethoscope or wand of probing can be used to identify it.  Or, just leave it until you get the intrinsic or item; worst case is it turns hostile and you have to kill it. Most pets are expendable and fairly easy to replace.